# format select with condition and regex

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for doing a select to format some values of my table.

I started to do code but still not working:

```
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN name ~* '.*\\yfede\\y.*' THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '\\yfede\\y', 'fed.') 
        ELSE name 
    END AS nom_modifie 
FROM InitialValues;
```

What I want is to modify on my select return value all occurrence of the words which contain "fede" with "fed." so "Federation" becomes "fed." but "Federacion" or all words which start with "Fede" should become "fed." too

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/4TNJ6o8G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` is redundant. Use this regexp `\m[[:alpha:]]*fede[[:alpha:]]*\M` with the query:

```sql
select
  regexp_replace(name, '\m[[:alpha:]]*fede[[:alpha:]]*\M', 'fed.', 'i') as nom_modifie 
from InitialValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '\yFEDE\w*', 'FED.') AS nom_modifie
From InitialVallues;
```